# Arranging 4 Piles into 5 Piles - Pigeonhole Principle

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

I read the following exercise in my combinatorics book in the section on the Pigeonhole Principle.

> There are four heaps of stones in our backyard. We rearrange them
>   into five heaps. Prove that at least two stones are placed into a smaller
>   heap.

I read the solution proof of the statement, but it didn't really seem to be derived or thought up easily - the idea behind the proof wasn't really intuitive to me.

Can anyone explain an easy to understand (intuitive) proof of the statement using the Pigeonhole Principle?

Comment: Does a 'heap of stones' have to contain at least two stones?

Comment: Can you tell us which part of the proof you don't get?

Comment: I also don't get it. If you don't do anything you are placing the stones into 5 piles of which one is empty. Are we missing some extra requirements here?

Comment: In addition to Pieter21's comment, you could also just move one stone to the new pile, contradicting the statement.

Comment: We cannot have an empty pile. There wouldn't be 5 piles of rocks.

Comment: @Mattos That does not disprove the statement, as there is the one stone that is in the new smaller heap of size 1, and the other stones from the heap that you took this stone from is now smaller in size and contains at least one stone.

Comment: Your statement says prove that _at least two stones_ are _placed_ into a smaller heap. Am I missing something in the wording?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a non-pigeonhole, but I think intuitive, proof. We say that a stone in a heap of size $k$ takes up $1/k$ of a heap. Suppose stone $i$ takes up $x_i$ of a heap in the first arrangement and $y_i$ of a heap in the second. Now we have $\sum_ix_i=4$, but $\sum_iy_i=5$, so $\sum_i(y_i-x_i)=1$. (This is where we assume the heaps are non-empty, so the sum over stones in each heap is $1$.)

Now for each $i$, $0<x_i,y_i\leq 1$. So $(y_i-x_i)<1$ for each $i$. So there must be at least two $i$ for which $(y_i-x_i)>0$. This corresponds to two stones which take up more of a heap than they did before, i.e. are in smaller heaps than they were before.